# Why is this c++ working? (variables with the same name)

Tags: c++, scope

Alright, I wanna know why this code is working, I just realized that I have two variables with the same name within the same scope.

I'm using g++ (gcc 4.4).

```
for(int k = 0 ; k < n ; k++)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            i = Tools::randomInt(0, n);
            bool exists = false;

            for(int k = 0 ; k < p_new_solution_size ; k++)
                if( i == p_new_solution[k] )
                {
                    exists = true;
                    break;
                }
            if(!exists)
                break;
        }

        p_new_solution[p_new_solution_size] = i;
        p_new_solution_size++;
    }
```

Comment: Try turning on `-Wall`, it might complain more?

Comment: `I have two variables with the same name within the same scope` Where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Alright, I wanna know why this code is working, I just realized that I have two variables with the same name within the same scope.

You seem confused about scopes.  They're not "within the same" scope... the for loop's k has it's own nested/inner scope.  More importantly, to see why the language allows it, consider:

```
#define DO_SOMETHING \
    do { for (int i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) std::cout << i << '\n'; } while (false)

void f()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
        DO_SOMETHING();
}
```

Here, the text substituted by the macro "DO_SOMETHING" gets evaluated in the same scope as i.  If you're writing DO_SOMETHING, you may need its expansion to store something in a variable, and settle on the identifier `i` - obviously you have no way of knowing if it'll already exist in the calling context.  You could try to pick something more obscure, but you'd have people using such convoluted variable names that their code maintainability suffered, and regardless sooner or later there would be a clash.  So, the language just lets the inner scopes introduce variables with the same name: the innermost match is used until its scope exits.

Even when you're not dealing with macros, it's a pain to have to stop and think about whether some outer scope is already using the same name.  If you know you just want a quick operation you can pop it an indepedent (nested) scope without considering that larger context (as long as you don't have code in there that actually wants to use the outer-scope variable: if you do then you can sometimes specify it explicitly (if it's scoped by namespaces and classes, but if it's in a function body you do end up needing to change your own loop variable's name (or create a reference or something to it before introducing your same-named variable)).

Comment: Ok, i got it, i mean.. after all these years of c++ and compilers, i never thought about this. I just have a little question: so the DO_SOMETHING() is in a different scope, but if it didn't shadow the i variable, it could use it's value, set by the outter loop right? What if it wasn't a macro, instead of DO_SOMETHING(), you had obj->do_this(). You would still change scope, but what else would change since this method can't use the earlier `i` value? i'm asking this to know the name of what changes, cuz i know how compilers work.. had a whole year about them, i just didnt knowthis worked on gcc

Comment: @polar: As you say, if DO_SOMETHING didn't shadow the outer i it could get or set it.  Occasionally, that's intentional: for example, a powerful way to implement enterprise-quality debugging with lots of orthogonal classifications assisting filtering is by having scoped error contexts.  In that model, you have a LOG macro that actually needs there to be an error context variable with a particular name in scope.  If you want to refine the reporting, you shadow the outer version and modify some classifications - provide a delta - but don't need to respecify everything on each LOG use.

Comment: If DO_SOMETHING was a function instead of a macro, then it couldn't access anything from the caller's scope (not just the function, but the namespace/class scopes above it that DO_SOMETHING isn't a member of).  It can still access scopes it is nested in, which isn't true for the macro (macro's don't remember which namespace they were defined in).

Comment: Then the "name" I was looking for is namespace/class scope. I remembered how these stuff works when they are being compiled, like a tree, with the root being global functions/variables (depends on language) and namespaces inheriting from other namespaces that are above and stuff like that. Thanks.

Comment: @polar: Yes - a tree's how I think about it too :-).

Answer (score 11):

The `k` in the inner for loop shadows (or hides) the `k` in the outer for loop.

You can declare multiple variables with the same name at different scopes.  A very simple example would be the following:

```
int main()
{
    int a;       // 'a' refers to the int until it is shadowed or its block ends
    { 
        float a; // 'a' refers to the float until the end of this block
    }            // 'a' now refers to the int again
}
```

Comment: Shouldn the compiler emit a warning that two variables have the same name on the same scope? I mean... i could use the outer `k` from the inner loop, so they are in the same scope.

Comment: You couldn't, because it is shadowed.

Comment: @polar:  It might give a warning, but it doesn't have to.  There are a lot of cases where this might happen.  For example you might have a variable at namespace scope or you might have a class member variable.

Comment: @polar: In general there aren't a lot of warnings enabled by default. `-Wshadow` turns on warnings for shadowing. (`-Wall` doesn't include `-Wshadow`, so you have to ask for it explicitly.)

Comment: So that' what `-Wall` is about.. always heard of it, but never used it. Thanks.

Comment: @polar: No, they are not "in the same scope". Each block `{}` introduces a new scope. However, names from an outer scope are visible in an inner scope (pertinent here) unless shadowed (occurring here).

Answer (score 3):

From the standard docs, *Sec 3.3.1*

> Every name is introduced in some portion of program text called a declarative region, which is the largest part of the
>   program in which that name is valid, that is, in which that name may be used as an unqualified name to refer to the
>   same entity. In general, each particular name is valid only within some possibly discontiguous portion of program text
>   called its scope. To determine the scope of a declaration, it is sometimes convenient to refer to the potential scope of
>   a declaration. The scope of a declaration is *the same* as its potential scope **unless the potential scope contains another
>   declaration of the same name.** In that case, the potential scope of the declaration in **the inner (contained) declarative
>   region is excluded from the scope of the declaration in the outer (containing) declarative region.**

It might sound confusing in your first read, but it does answer your question.

The potential scope is same as the scope of the declaration unless another (inner) declaration occurs. If occurred, the potential scope of the outer declaration is *removed* and **just** the inner declaration's holds.

Hope am clear and it helps..

Comment: You were clear, but that text takes some time to be totally understanded. But it sure answers my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are allowed to have two variables of the same name within the same scope, but not within the same declaration space.  The compiler takes the most-local variable of the appropriate name, similar to how you can 'hide' global variables of name X with a member variable of name X.  You should be getting a warning though.

Comment: This isn't meant to sound narky, I'm genuinely curious - for my own learning benefit can someone explain to me what was incorrect in the above that would have caused a downvote?  Cheers.

Comment: I thought the samething when i saw it there.. why would someone downvote this answer? just because it's simple yet understandable?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but you deserve some explanation and I'll guess.  I suspect it's just a matter of terminology.  The idea is right, but you're either sharing or accepting polar's idea that the two ks were in the same scope.  They weren't - they were in an inner scope nested within an outer scope.  I'm not sure where you got your understanding of scopes versus "declaration spaces", but I've never heard of declaration spaces before (26 years programming, most in C/C++).

Comment: I'd had it explained to me using "declaration spaces" and it looks like the terminology was non-standard but your description makes sense.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ the variable  scope is limited by the *braces* so the following code is valid for the compiler:

```
int k()
{ 
    int k=0;
    {  
        int k=1;
        {
           int k=2;               
        }    
    } 
    return k; // guess which k-variable is returned! 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean *branches* or *braces*?