# Why does my C++ code compile even with doubly declared variable?

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn C++ from the book Accelerated C++. At the end of Chapter 1 there is an exercise that tripped me. Essentially, I am wondering why the following code compiles and runs perfectly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
   {
        const std::string s  = "a string";
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
        {
            std::cout << s << std::endl;
            const std::string s = "another string";
            std::cout << s << std::endl;
        };
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to me that I am doubly declaring the string s, and from my understanding this is illegal. Could you help me understand this better? Thanks. The output this produces is:

```
a string
a string
another string
```

Comment: Strongly related/possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151203/why-is-this-c-working-variables-with-the-same-name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, you are allowed to redeclare a variable in a nested scope. Within that scope, the redeclared variable takes precedence.

See  [basic.scope.hiding] for a standard reference:

> A name can be hidden by an explicit declaration of that same name in a nested declarative region or derived
>   class

Comment: Thanks. My understanding was that the inner scope is contained within the outer, and therefore as far as the first `s` is concerned, it was being declared twice. So I think that my understanding of scopes is a little off. The concept is not as "linear" as I had thought.

Comment: @teachMeCpp: Indeed. It at least logical, though. Unlike PHP where a variable declared in what looks like an inner scope can be visible in an outer scope (definition of scope is weird)

Comment: I asked the following question to Filip below: I kind of see that it is logical, but I fail to envision what circumstances this feature would be useful in. Could you comment on this?

Comment: @teachMeCpp: The behavior follows the principle of least surprise in my opinion. If some nefarious library doesn't use namespaces properly, they may have a bunch of variables accessible from the global scope. Then, when you declare your own variable with the same name in your nested scope, you don't get a compiler error. It would be surprising if you did on account of the other global variables that you didn't even know about.

Comment: Ahh, I see, that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These are two seperate variable because they are declared in a different scope. The scope of a variable is the 'area' of code in which it's visible.

The outer `s` is overwritten with `s` in inner body.

Comment: Thanks. As I noted in my comment to AndyG, I think my understanding of scopes is off. I see that the outer `s` is overwritten in the inner body, but as soon as the code exits the inner body the outer `s` is restored. I am wondering,  what situations is this feature useful in? To a novice like me it seems like it is definitely not foolproof.

Comment: Yes becouse `s` which was in inner body goes out of scope, so there is only the outher `s` :-)

Comment: Oh right, I agree, the other `s` should definitely be restored. I was wondering when this feature of allowing redeclarations within nested scopes would be useful. Does this not cause problems?

Comment: Nevermind, @AndyG answered my query above and I see why this is useful. Thanks.

Comment: It might cause problems especially if any other programer is reading your code and there are two variables with same names. Otherwise it shouldnt cause any problems since they are in different scopes. Bigger problem is when youve got global variables with same names in one project. But thats another story. You are welcome. :-)