# Why did the compiler assign different memory address to the same variable, after re-defining the variable?

Tags: c, memory, scope, shadowing

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("%p\n",&i);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int i = 10;
        printf("%d %p\n", i,&i);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

First we defined a variable  `i` (just after main). Then at the start of `for` loop we defined the same variable `i` again. So, inside `for` loop, value of `i` is 10. The `for` loop must iterate only once, since `i>5` after first iteration. But to my surprise the output is as follows:

```
0x7ffe8b799da0
10 0x7ffe8b799da4
10 0x7ffe8b799da4
10 0x7ffe8b799da4
10 0x7ffe8b799da4
10 0x7ffe8b799da4
```

My questions are:
1) Why is the compiler considering the initial defined variable `i` while executing `i<5;i++` instruction and, not the re-defined variable `i`? (after first iteration).

2) Why did compiler assign different memory address to same variable identifier `i`?

Comment: Because it isn't the same variable. It is two different variables with the same name. Internally, it will use some manner of "name mangling" to keep them apart.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151203/why-is-this-c-working-variables-with-the-same-name Its duplicated.

Comment: Take a look at: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151203/why-is-this-c-working-variables-with-the-same-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151203/why-is-this-c-working-variables-with-the-same-name) It's duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the compiler considering the initial defined variable i while
>   executing i<5;i++ instruction and, not the re-defined variable i?
>   (after first iteration).

Because the re-defined (shadowing) variable isn't in scope yet. If you remove the first definition, you get an "identifier undeclared" error. This also doesn't change after the first iteration of the loop as it is determined at compile time.

> 2) Why did compiler assign different memory address to same variable
>   identifier i?

Even though you can't access the outer `int i` inside the loop as the second one shadows it, it still exists and therefore needs its own memory. It's not overwritten by the other `int i`. You can see that by putting a `printf("%d\n", i);` after the loop - it will print `5`, because that's the value of that `i` after loop.

---

On another note, the `i++;` at the end of the loop has no effect because it affects the `i` inside the loop, which goes out of scope right after the `i++;`. This is unlike the `i++;` in the `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)`, which increases the outer `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two different variables both named `i`, so obviously the situation is going to be confusing!  For every `i` in the program, we have to ask: is this the "outer" `i`, or the "inner" `i`?

Here's your program again, with the variables renamed for clarity:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i1;
    printf("%p\n",&i1);
    for (i1 = 0; i1 < 5; i1++)
    {
        int i2 = 10;
        printf("%d %p\n", i2,&i2);
        i2++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To your specific question, the reason the loop runs 5 times is that the loop control `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)` is unquestionably using the *outer* `i`.