# Trying to define strings in an if statment in C++

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I want to have a gender system in what I'm coding, so in dialogue there are pronouns, but since the strings are defined in an `if` statement they come up blank. Is there a better way to do this?

```cpp
int gender;
string pronoun;
string pronoun1;
string pronoun2;
string pronouns3;
string namingGender;

cout << "Please enter your gender \n1. Male \n2. Female \n3. Other" << endl;
cin >> gender;
if (gender == 1) {
    string namingGender = " saucy sir";
    string pronoun = " he ";
    string pronoun1 = " him ";
    string pronoun2 = " his ";
    string pronoun3 = " he's ";
    cout << "Have fun playing Insert-Name-Here!" << endl;
}
else if (gender == 2) {
    string namingGender = " manseva madam";
    string pronous = " she ";
    string pronou1 = " her ";
    string pronoun2 = " her ";
    string pronoun3 = " she's ";
    cout << "Have fun playing Insert-Name-Here!" << endl;
}
else if (gender == 3) {
    string nammingGender = " majestic mate";
    string pronoun = " they ";
    string pronoun1 = " them ";
    string pronoun2 = " their ";
    string pronoun3 = " they're ";
    cout << "Have fun playing Insert-Name-Here!" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "You  did not enter 1 2 or 3...guess your other than" << endl;
    string nammingGender = " majestic mate";
    string pronoun = " they ";
    string pronoun1 = " them ";
    string pronoun2 = " their ";
    string pronoun3 = " they're ";
    cout << "Have fun playing Insert-Name-Here!" << endl;
}
    
cout << "By the way, what is your name... " << namingGender << "?" << endl;
cin >> playerName;
```

Comment: You don't need to define them each time, just re-assign them with a different value. Like `if (gender == 1) { namingGender = " saucy sir"; pronoun = " he "; ... }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151203/why-is-this-c-working-variables-with-the-same-name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: Is there a better way to do this or fix this?

A: Yes:

```
string namingGender;
cout << "Please enter your gender \n1. Male \n2. Female \n3. Other" << endl;
cin >> gender;
if (gender == 1) {
   namingGender = " saucy sir";
   ...
else if (gender == 2) {
   namingGender = " manseva madam";
```

What you've shown is a good example of ["variable shadowing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).  It's not what you intended to do.

["Declare"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_(computer_programming)) outside of your if/else blocks; then ["assign"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)) on a per-case basis.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring some variables before your `if`s that you are ignoring.  You are declaring more variables with the same names inside your `if`s, which *shadow* the earlier variables.  Use the variables you already have, eg:

```cpp
int gender;

string namingGender;
string pronoun;
string pronoun1;
string pronoun2;
string pronoun3;

cout << "Please enter your gender \n1. Male \n2. Female \n3. Other" << endl;
cin >> gender;
if (gender == 1) {
    namingGender = " saucy sir";
    pronoun = " he ";
    pronoun1 = " him ";
    pronoun2 = " his ";
    pronoun3 = " he's ";
}
else if (gender == 2) {
    namingGender = " manseva madam";
    pronoun = " she ";
    pronoun1 = " her ";
    pronoun2 = " her ";
    pronoun3 = " she's ";
}
else if (gender == 3) {
    namingGender = " majestic mate";
    pronoun = " they ";
    pronoun1 = " them ";
    pronoun2 = " their ";
    pronoun3 = " they're ";
}
else {
    cout << "You  did not enter 1 2 or 3...guess your other than" << endl;
    namingGender = " majestic mate";
    pronoun = " they ";
    pronoun1 = " them ";
    pronoun2 = " their ";
    pronoun3 = " they're ";
}
    
cout << "Have fun playing Insert-Name-Here!" << endl;

cout << "By the way, what is your name... " << namingGender << "?" << endl;
cin >> playerName;

// use pronoun(1|2|3) as needed...
```

That being said, you should define all of the strings up front, and then use `gender` to access them when needed, eg:

```cpp
struct genderStrings
{
    string namingGender;
    string pronoun;
    string pronoun1;
    string pronoun2;
    string pronoun3;
};

const genderStrings c_genderStrings[] = {
    {" saucy sir", " he ", " him ", " his ", " he's "},
    {" manseva madam", " she ", " her ", " her ", " she's "},
    {" majestic mate", " they ", " them ", " their ", " they're "}
};

...

int gender;

cout << "Please enter your gender \n1. Male \n2. Female \n3. Other" << endl;
cin >> gender;

if (gender < 1 || gender > 3) {
    cout << "You  did not enter 1 2 or 3...guess your other than" << endl;
    gender = 3;
}

const genderStrings &gstrs = c_genderStrings[gender-1];

cout << "Have fun playing Insert-Name-Here!" << endl;

cout << "By the way, what is your name... " << gstrs.namingGender << "?" << endl;
cin >> playerName;

// use gstrs.pronoun(1|2|3) as needed...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the variables outside the if-else blocks and then use them (assign values to them) inside if-else blocks.

**Note:** there were some typos in the code posted in the question. I have corrected them.

```
int gender;
string pronoun;
string pronoun1;
string pronoun2;
string pronoun3;
string namingGender;

cout << "Please enter your gender \n1. Male \n2. Female \n3. Other" << endl;
cin >> gender;
if (gender == 1) {
    namingGender = " saucy sir";
    pronoun = " he ";
    pronoun1 = " him ";
    pronoun2 = " his ";
    pronoun3 = " he's ";
}
else if (gender == 2) {
    namingGender = " manseva madam";
    pronoun = " she ";
    pronoun1 = " her ";
    pronoun2 = " her ";
    pronoun3 = " she's ";
}
else if (gender == 3) {
    namingGender = " majestic mate";
    pronoun = " they ";
    pronoun1 = " them ";
    pronoun2 = " their ";
    pronoun3 = " they're ";
}
else {
    cout << "You  did not enter 1 2 or 3...guess your other than" << endl;
    namingGender = " majestic mate";
    pronoun = " they ";
    pronoun1 = " them ";
    pronoun2 = " their ";
    pronoun3 = " they're ";
}
cout << "Have fun playing Insert-Name-Here!" << endl;
cout << "By the way, what is your name... " << namingGender << "?" << endl;
string playerName;
cin >> playerName;
```